# Missing ) after argument list. (line 108, file "test")

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm receiving an error message for this line (line 108) of Google Apps Script:

```
var hash = Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(data, "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"apiKey"\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n)")
```

The error says:

> Missing ) after argument list. (line 108, file "test")

What is wrong with that line of code?

Comment: To many double quotes gives you an impossible string in the second argument on the `computeRsaSha256Signature`

Comment: Use a + somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your api key is a variable here: Your string for the second parameter terminates before "apiKey", because you didn't put a "+" to join your multiple arguments together. As a result, the program is expecting to see a closing parentheses, since the string is finished. What you need to do:

```
var hash = Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(data, "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" + apiKey + "\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n)")
```

The comma separates the parameters, with the second parameter being made of 3 pieces:

1. "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
2. Your variable, apiKey
3. "\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n)"

I'd recommend that you review Javascript concepts at Codecademy, or do some reading on W3Schools, to get a hang of the syntax.